# Memory not released in ios view hierarchy

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have an iOS-App which uses ARC. I don't use InterfaceBuilder, all UI is generated manually. In that app I have several UIViewControllers with SubViewControllers. Those ViewControllers a tied together from a menu (-ViewController) who pushes them on the stack.

My problem is, that memory doesn't get freed when switching between the ViewControllers.

Is it wrong to keep references to the SubViewControllers like this?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController subViewController1; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController subViewController2;
```

viewDidUnload never gets called. Has anyone a good example how to build a clean view hierarchy?

Comment: viewDidUnload only gets called in low memory conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely has nothing to do with ARC. viewDidUnload is only called on a view controller when the view property is released / set to nil and this typically only happens if the app receives a memory warning.

Try triggering a memory warning in the simulator and see if that causes your viewDidUnload method to fire. If it does then everything is fine. If not, you are probably over-retaining your views somehow, perhaps by assigning them to other strongly retained properties.

There are exceptions to the view-retaining policy, for example the UINavigationController frees up views in its view controller stack if they aren't frontmost, but it does that by simply setting the view of its child controllers to nil when they're covered by another controller's view.

If you want your views to be released when they aren't onscreen, either set the controller's view property to nil in the viewDidDisappear: method, or stop retaining the view controllers when their views aren't onscreen and just create fresh controller instances each time you need to display them (that way both the controller and view will be released when not in use).

Answer (score 5):

By assigning the view controllers which get pushed on the stack to a strong instance variable / property, they will not be deallocated when popped off of the stack. The strong properties are holding on to the pushed view controllers even after they are popped off the stack, so they never get to a state where they can be deallocated.

Normally I do something like the following when pushing a next-level-down view controller onto the navigation stack:

```
SLSMoleculeSearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SLSMoleculeSearchViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];
```

Under ARC, the new view controller will be allocated and will be retained on creation. When pushed onto the navigation stack, it will be retained once by the navigation controller. Because this new view controller is not referred to after being pushed, and is not assigned to a strong property or instance variable, ARC will release it after the second line.

Remember, it's still being retained by the navigation controller, so it's still live in memory. However, once the navigation controller pops it off the stack this view controller will be released. Since nothing is holding on to it at that point, it will be deallocated as expected.

If for some reason you need to maintain a reference to this sub view controller in your higher-level view controller, you could use a `weak` property or `__weak` instance variable. This will not hold on to the view controller, and will turn to nil once the controller is deallocated.

`weak` references are only supported for applications that target iOS 5.0, though, so you won't be able to do this for anything that needs to run on iOS 4.0. The 4.0-compatible `unsafe_unretained` property is not something I would recommend in this case, due to the danger of a pointer to deallocated memory.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, cleared up my suspicions to how I should create view controllers in order for them to be released as soon as possible!